# Regex to match Ip:Port

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex to match Ip:Port form html code, but some some reason I'm only getting the first match returned, then it stops.

my code:

```
       Match m = Regex.Match(_theHtmlCode, @"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\:\d{1,8}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

       if (m.Success)
       {
           if(m.Groups[0].Value != "")
           {
               resultsFound.Add(m.Groups[0].Value);
           }

       }
```

Any ideas how i could get it to add all of the matches into resultsFound?

Answer (score 5):

`var m = Regex.Matches(_theHtmlCode, @"\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\:\d{1,8}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`
and this regex can get wrong ip, this matches only true ip: `((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):\d+`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Regex.Matches` method not the `Regex.Match` method. This returns a `MatchCollection` rather than an individual `Match`, with the collection containing all matches for the regular expression.

Comment: Ohh, how would my modified code look with the matches instead? Getting error here and there when i switched to matches and matchcollection

Comment: Get the `MatchCollection` and iterate through it with `foreach (var m in matches)`. Inside the look, keep your `if (m.Success)` block.